# Concatenate 2 columns with a line between the concatenation. column A is a number column B is a number with ceros on front I need to keep the ceros

Tags: excel, vba

```
ID#1   ID#2   Need Results
 1      001       1-001
 1      002       1-002
 1      003       1-003
 2      001       2-001
 2      002       2-002
```

I use this code, but the result is a number.

```vba
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 6000
    Cells(i, 3) = CStr(Cells(i, 1)) & " - " & CStr(Cells(i, 2))
Next i
```

Comment: format the cells as text: `Range(C:C).NumberFormat = '@'` before the loop.

Comment: `Cells(i, 3).Value = CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value) & " - " & CStr(Cells(i, 2).Text)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Format()` function

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 6000
    Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " - " & Format(Cells(i, 2).Value, "000")
Next i
```

While a "formula" way way could be:

```
With Range("C1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2] & "" - "" & TEXT(RC[-1],""000"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: `TEXT(RC[-1],""000"")"`  surely ?

Comment: @CDP1802, yes. what's puzzling you about that?

Comment: @CDP1802, oh I see it now: yes it has to be "RC[-1]" ; just edited the answer